# C# string manipulation by rules using regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace, mask

I have a situation..
Having a string which can contain numbers,letters, and some symbols, I want to make an extraction from it or to make some replacements based on some "rules".
I thing the best is to give some examples of possible situations and what I want to do (display):

```
String           Display1   or  Display2

AB_X345           X345         or  ###X345  
AB_1234            1234        or  ###1234  
X987_TEXT_4567    X9874567     or  X987######4567  
X987TEXT4567      X9874567     or  X987####4567  
X798TEXT          X798         or  X798####  
789TEXT            789         or  789####  
X400              X400         or  X400
```

So practically when I find an X followed by numbers I want to display them. If some text appear, I don't want it displayed or I want it masked with a character(#).
In case no X is present, I want to display only the numbers. 
Is Regex the easyest way of doing this? (I am not familiar with regex-just had a bird's eye view on it).
Can all the rules be gathered in a single regex expression or is to complicated?

Thank you for any sugestions

Comment: Where are the spaces before `1234` and `789` from?

Comment: The spaces have no semnification :) sorry..i just wanted to see better that there is no X. About the case you pointed, this won't appear.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, 
    @"\D       # Match a non-digit character
    (?<!       # unless...
     X         #  it's an X
     (?=\d)    #  which is followed by a digit.
    )          # End of lookbehind", 
    "", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Change the last line to

```
    "#", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

to mask the characters with `#` instead of removing them.

Comment: Given his examples (the use of the word TEXT) I would say that `LEX12340`=>`1234` and not `X1234`. And you are catching non-european digits with this regex.

Comment: @stema It's so simple that deciding if a regex is right or wrong is nearly more difficult than writing it. :-)

Comment: Thank you guys, i will try all the solutions this evening, and mark the one it will work better. :)

Comment: @stema: Well, in `TEXT` the `X` isn't followed by a number, so it's removed.

Comment: I admit I didn't understand the question very well, but I'm pretty sure that is the same as `(?!X\d)\D`.

Comment: Uh, yeah, Kobi, of course you're right. If you post that as an answer, I'll remove mine out of shame :)

Comment: I can see that Regex is quite a thing! :) And gives a lot of possibilities. I will mark Tim's answer but I can use the shorten version of Kobi :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this for Display 1: `@"(?<![A-Za-z])X[0-9]+|[0-9]+"`

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<![A-Za-z])X[0-9]+|[0-9]+");
var matches = rx.Matches("X987_TEXT_4567");

var result = "";

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    result += match.Value;
}
```

Under C# 4.0 you can even do

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<![A-Za-z])(?<1>X[0-9]+)?(?:(?:[^0-9]*)(?<1>[0-9]+))*");
var match = rx.Match("X987_TEXT_4567_123");
var res = string.Concat(match.Groups[1].Captures.OfType<Capture>().Select(p => p.Value));
```

But the regex at this point becomes a little unreadable :-)

Comment: @stema Changed it to zero width negative lookbehind

Comment: Nice solution also ;) And thank you for giving a version for C# 4.0 also but I have only 3.5 :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

**`X\d|\d`**

OR

**`/X\d|\d/g`**

This will select only digits or digit starts with **'X'**

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, check the example below and test it.

```
\d?X[0-9]+|[0-9]
```

Example:
http://rubular.com/r/cA5Y49pCtV

Comment: The link you gave here is very handy :) Thanks! I found alos some tools for regex check, but this is the simpliest :)

Comment: No problem glad I could help you out.